# How can I get the Struts2 interceptor init param

Tags: struts2

I define a interceptor in struts.xml like this :

```
<interceptor name="ssoAuthenticationInterceptor" class="net.ysccc.sso.authentication.AuthenticationInterceptor">
            <param name="casServerLoginUrl">http://localhost:8080/cas/login</param>
            <param name="serverName">http://localhost:8080</param>
            <param name="renew">false</param>
            <param name="gateway">false</param>
        </interceptor>
```

now in the interceptor class I want get the param, there a way is define getter setter method in the class, but I don't want use  this way, could anyone tell me how to do?

Comment: What wrong with using setters?

Comment: @AleksandrM, nothing, I just want to know whether there has another way to do this

Comment: @DigengTianhan Describe why do you need it, and why you can't use bean properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Getters and Setters for All the params, attributes must be public in Interceptor.

```
casServerLoginUrl
serverName
renew
gateway
```